# Working out the max value with 2 digits and single digits number

Tags: python, csv, max

I'm currently developing a code which works out the highest score out of the score it has on the csv file. For example if the score is 10 and 4 , the highest score should be 4. However it does not work if the number is 10. It works fine if the number is 5 and 7 or any 1 digit number.

http://postimg.org/image/7a0pgl6x3/

This is the code that I'm using to workout the max value out of the scores each user has.

```
high = max(row[2:4]) # finds the highest score from the row 2:4
high = str("0") + str(high) # adds a 0 in front of the high score so that it could be used for sorting
row.insert( 6, high) #insert the high value on row 6
write.writerows([row[:7]])
```

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: " For example if the score is 10 and 4 , the highest score should be 4." Why is that?

Comment: You tagged `floating-point`, but it looks like you're working with values directly from a CSV file, which will all be strings. Strings are sorted in alphabetical order, so 1 and 10 will both be before 4. Convert them into numbers to get the sort order you're expecting.

Comment: @Totem Sorry , i meant 10 should be the highest score. My bad :p

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go ahead and guess here that you meant 10 should be the high score when comparing 10 and 4, and isn't. In that case, your problem is almost certainly caused by using strings:

```
In [12]: max("10","4")
Out[12]: '4'

In [13]: max(10,4)
Out[13]: 10
```

I assume from writerows that you're using the `csv` library. That library doesn't do *any* conversion away from strings, so while you think that you're dealing with numbers, you're actually dealing with strings, and when comparing strings "4" and "10" are compared first by their first characters...

A good fix would be to convert when you read in the csv file, but a quick fix is just to use the following:

```
high = max(int(x) for x in row[2:4])
```